# Plot Gauss Bell Curve based on a data set?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gauss

I want to plot the bell curve to show the distribution of the data around the mean, with one and two standard deviations. Possibly, comparing two data sets.

I have the following code from @Stefan Pinnow

```
% here are your data, just multiplied by 10^9
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
    2.9954
    3.1314
    3.1155
    3.094
    2.8861
    3.0875
    2.9685
    3.0532
    2.9003
    3.0931
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use at least this `compat' level so there is no need to prefix
        % coordinates with "axis cs:"
        compat=1.11,
        %
        /pgf/declare function={
            % `mu' and `sigma' where calculated in Excel using above data
            mu=3.03250;
            sigma=0.0894182;
            % declare gaussian function
            gauss(\x)=1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-mu)^2)/(2*sigma^2));
            % precalculate some values
            yA=gauss(mu-2*sigma);
            yB=gauss(mu-sigma);
            % constant to simply change calculating `domain' and x axis limits
            C=2.5;
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % set axis limits and `domain'
            xmin=mu-C*sigma,
            xmax=mu+C*sigma,
            ymin=0,
            domain=mu-C*sigma:mu+C*sigma,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % nothing changed here
            samples=100,
            axis lines*=left,
            xlabel=$x$,
            every axis x label/.style={
                at=(current axis.right of origin),
                anchor=west,
            },
            height=5cm,
            width=11cm,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            axis on top,
            hide y axis,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % use ticks just at the coordinates of the first `\addplot' ...
            xtick=data,
            % and show the below labels for these ticks
            xticklabels={
                $\mu - 2\sigma$,
                $\mu - \sigma$,
                $\mu$
            },
        ]

        % just a dummy plot used for the `xticklabels'
            \addplot [draw=none,fill=none] coordinates {
                (mu-2*sigma,0)
                (mu-sigma,0)
                (mu,0)
            };
        % plot the data point and the corresponding gauss curve
            \addplot [only marks,cyan]
                table [x index=0,y expr=0] {data.txt};
            \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(x)};

        % add some lines and labels
            % draw vertical lines
            \draw [gray]
                (mu-2*sigma,0) -- coordinate (A left)  (mu-2*sigma,yA)
                (mu+2*sigma,0) -- coordinate (A right) (mu+2*sigma,yA);
            \draw [gray]
                (mu-sigma,0)   -- coordinate (B left)  (mu-sigma,yB)
                (mu+sigma,0)   -- coordinate (B right) (mu+sigma,yB);
            % draw labels
            \draw [latex-latex]
                (A left) -- node [fill=white] {$0.954$} (A right);
            \draw [latex-latex]
                (B left) -- node [fill=white] {$0.683$} (B right);

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The graph does not adapt ty my data!

my data is:

```
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
    2.132687
    2.634472
    2.697368
    2.917756
    2.582803
    2.32906
    2.009636
    2.483408
    1.778771
    2.46634
\end{filecontents}

mu=2.403;
sigma=0.327;
```

Comment: I am not sure if I got the question right. So could you please show your **new** (not working) code + the resulting image. (You can delete the "old" code and instead add a reference/link to the old question or answer.)

Comment: Thank you for reaching back! The shape of the curve does not adapt to the data, i.e. the width and the length of the curve should vary based on the standard deviation. I tried different data sets and the shape remains the same. I could somehow adapt the shape only by changing the constant 'C'!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think now I have understood your "problem".

In the code of your question x is given **relative** to μ and σ. And the y range isn't specified at all, so `ymax` is chosen from the calculated value. But `height` is given and thus, regardless of the the chosen values of μ and σ the curve looks the same. You would immediately see that the calculated values indeed change, if you just set a fixed `ymax` value and then change the values of μ and σ.

To prove that I plotted both your curves in one `axis` environment with only minor changes in code to account for changing values of μ and σ.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
% here are your data, just multiplied by 10^9
\begin{filecontents}{data1.txt}
    2.9954
    3.1314
    3.1155
    3.094
    2.8861
    3.0875
    2.9685
    3.0532
    2.9003
    3.0931
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data2.txt}
    2.132687
    2.634472
    2.697368
    2.917756
    2.582803
    2.32906
    2.009636
    2.483408
    1.778771
    2.46634
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use at least this `compat' level so there is no need to prefix
        % coordinates with "axis cs:"
        compat=1.11,
        %
        /pgf/declare function={
            % `mu' and `sigma' where calculated in Excel using above data
            mu1=3.03250;
            sigma1=0.0894182;
            mu2=2.403;
            sigma2=0.327;
            % declare gaussian function
            gauss(\x,\mu,\sigma)=1/(\sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\mu)^2)/(2*\sigma^2));
            % precalculate some values
            yA1=gauss(mu1-2*sigma1,mu1,sigma1);
            yB1=gauss(mu1-sigma1,mu1,sigma1);
            % constant to simply change calculating `domain' and x axis limits
            C=2.5;
            %
            xmin=min(mu1-C*sigma1,mu2-C*sigma2);
            xmax=max(mu1+C*sigma1,mu2+C*sigma2);
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % set axis limits and `domain'
            xmin=xmin,
            xmax=xmax,
            ymin=0,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % nothing changed here
            samples=100,
            axis lines*=left,
            xlabel=$x$,
            every axis x label/.style={
                at=(current axis.right of origin),
                anchor=west,
            },
            height=5cm,
            width=11cm,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            axis on top,
            hide y axis,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % use ticks just at the coordinates of the first `\addplot' ...
            xtick=data,
            % and show the below labels for these ticks
            xticklabels={
                $\mu - 2\sigma$,
                $\mu - \sigma$,
                $\mu$
            },
            smooth,
        ]

        % just a dummy plot used for the `xticklabels'
            \addplot [draw=none,fill=none] coordinates {
                (mu1-2*sigma1,0)
                (mu1-sigma1,0)
                (mu1,0)
            };
        % plot the data point and the corresponding gauss curve
            \addplot [only marks,cyan]
                table [x index=0,y expr=0] {data1.txt};
            \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black,domain=mu1-C*sigma1:mu1+C*sigma1]
                {gauss(x,mu1,sigma1)};

        % plot the data point and the corresponding gauss curve
            \addplot [only marks,orange]
                table [x index=0,y expr=0] {data2.txt};
            \addplot [very thick,orange!75!black,domain=mu2-C*sigma2:mu2+C*sigma2]
                {gauss(x,mu2,sigma2)};

        % add some lines and labels
            % draw vertical lines
            \draw [gray]
                (mu1-2*sigma1,0) -- coordinate (A left)  (mu1-2*sigma1,yA1)
                (mu1+2*sigma1,0) -- coordinate (A right) (mu1+2*sigma1,yA1);
            \draw [gray]
                (mu1-sigma1,0)   -- coordinate (B left)  (mu1-sigma1,yB1)
                (mu1+sigma1,0)   -- coordinate (B right) (mu1+sigma1,yB1);
            % draw labels
            \draw [latex-latex]
                (A left) -- node [fill=white] {$0.954$} (A right);
            \draw [latex-latex]
                (B left) -- node [fill=white] {$0.683$} (B right);

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: You are right. I also see the problem now. This is a smooth solution, Thanks! Check my updated solution (i made some changes).

Answer (score 2):

Somehow this code works!

```
% here are your data, just multiplied by 10^9
\begin{filecontents}{data1.txt}
    2.132687
    2.634472
    2.697368
    2.917756
    2.582803
    2.32906
    2.009636
    2.483408
    1.778771
    2.46634
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
    2.065643
    2.031713
    2.055865
    2.365157
    2.227517
    2.008509
    2.790536
    2.167367
    2.269939
    2.065643
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use at least this `compat' level so there is no need to prefix
        % coordinates with "axis cs:"
        compat=1.11,
        %
        /pgf/declare function={
            % `mu' and `sigma' where calculated in Excel using above data
            mu=2.205;
            sigma=0.234;
            % declare gaussian function
            gauss(\x)=1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-mu)^2)/(2*sigma^2));
            % precalculate some values
            yA=gauss(mu-2*sigma);
            yB=gauss(mu-sigma);
            % constant to simply change calculating `domain' and x axis limits
            C=4
            ;
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % set axis limits and `domain'
            xmin=mu-C*sigma,
            xmax=mu+C*sigma,
            ymin=0,
            domain=mu-C*sigma:mu+C*sigma,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % nothing changed here
            samples=100,
            axis lines*=left,
            xlabel=$x$,
            every axis x label/.style={
                at=(current axis.right of origin),
                anchor=west,
            },
            height=5cm,
            width=11cm,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            axis on top,
            hide y axis,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % use ticks just at the coordinates of the first `\addplot' ...
            xtick=data,
            % and show the below labels for these ticks
            xticklabels={
                $\mu - 2\sigma$,
                $\mu - \sigma$,
                $\mu$,
                $\mu + \sigma$,
                $\mu + 2\sigma$
            },
        ]

        % just a dummy plot used for the `xticklabels'
            \addplot [draw=none,fill=none] coordinates {
                (mu-2*sigma,0)
                (mu-sigma,0)
                (mu,0)
                (mu+sigma,0)
                (mu+2*sigma,0)
            };
        % plot the data point and the corresponding gauss curve
            \addplot [only marks,blue]
                table [x index=0,y expr=0] {data.txt};
            \addplot [very thick,red!50!black] {gauss(x)};

        % add some lines and labels
            % draw vertical lines
            \draw [gray]
                (mu-2*sigma,0) -- coordinate (A left)  (mu-2*sigma,yA)
                (mu+2*sigma,0) -- coordinate (A right) (mu+2*sigma,yA);
            \draw [gray]
                (mu-sigma,0)   -- coordinate (B left)  (mu-sigma,yB)
                (mu+sigma,0)   -- coordinate (B right) (mu+sigma,yB);
            % draw labels
            \draw [latex-latex]
                (A left) -- node [fill=white] {$95 \%$} (A right);
            \draw [latex-latex]
                (B left) -- node [fill=white] {$68 \%$} (B right);

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

output:
[image]

Update 1:

This code adapts to the set of data. I also plotted three plots in the same graph to show the differences. However, it remains a problem to display legendary correctly. The *\mu* values are displayed as plot, therefore the legendary takes it as a plot!

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
% here are your data, just multiplied by 10^9
% TEE
\begin{filecontents}{data1.txt}
    2.132687
    2.634472
    2.697368
    2.917756
    2.582803
    2.32906
    2.009636
    2.483408
    1.778771
    2.46634
\end{filecontents}
% ICE
\begin{filecontents}{data2.txt}
    2.065643
    2.031713
    2.055865
    2.365157
    2.227517
    2.008509
    2.790536
    2.167367
    2.269939
    2.065643
\end{filecontents}

% L742
\begin{filecontents}{data3.txt}
    1.67097
    1.65911
    2.96315
    2.46577
    1.61159
    1.46357
    1.59512
    1.87797
    2.37143
    1.16881
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use at least this `compat' level so there is no need to prefix
        % coordinates with "axis cs:"
        compat=1.11,
        %
        /pgf/declare function={
            % `mu' and `sigma' where calculated in Excel using above data
            mu1=2.40;
            sigma1=0.33;
            mu2=2.2;
            sigma2=0.22;
            mu3=1.88;
            sigma3=0.52;
            % declare gaussian function
            gauss(\x,\mu,\sigma)=1/(\sigma*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\mu)^2)/(2*\sigma^2));
            % precalculate some values
            yA1=gauss(mu1-2*sigma1,mu1,sigma1);
            yB1=gauss(mu1-sigma1,mu1,sigma1);
            yA2=gauss(mu2-2*sigma2,mu2,sigma2);
            yB2=gauss(mu2-sigma2,mu2,sigma2);
            yA3=gauss(mu3-2*sigma3,mu3,sigma3);
            yB3=gauss(mu3-sigma3,mu3,sigma3);
            % constant to simply change calculating `domain' and x axis limits
            C=2.5;
            %
            xmin=min(mu1-C*sigma1,mu2-C*sigma2,mu3-C*sigma3);
            xmax=max(mu1+C*sigma1,mu2+C*sigma2,mu3+C*sigma3);
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            legend pos=north west,
            % set axis limits and `domain'
            xmin=xmin,
            xmax=xmax,
            ymin=0,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % nothing changed here
            samples=100,
            axis lines*=left,
            xlabel=\tiny{$Error$},
            every axis x label/.style={
                at=(current axis.right of origin),
                anchor=west,
            },
            height=5cm,
            width=11cm,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            axis on top,
            hide y axis,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % use ticks just at the coordinates of the first `\addplot' ...
            xtick=data,
            % and show the below labels for these ticks
            xticklabels={
                $\mu_{1}$,
                $\mu_{2}$,
                $\mu_{3}$
            },
            smooth,
        ]

        % just a dummy plot used for the `xticklabels'
            \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {
                (mu1,0)
                (mu2,0)
                (mu3,0)
            };
          \addlegendentry[draw = none]{\tiny{$\mu_{1}=2.40$, $\mu_{2}=2.2$, $\mu_{3}=1.88$}}
        % plot the data point and the corresponding gauss curve TEE
            \addplot [very thick,blue,domain=mu1-C*sigma1:mu1+C*sigma1]
                {gauss(x,mu1,sigma1)};
            \addlegendentry{\footnotesize{TEE}}
            
        % plot the data point and the corresponding gauss curve ICE
            \addplot [very thick,red,domain=mu2-C*sigma2:mu2+C*sigma2]
                {gauss(x,mu2,sigma2)};
            \addlegendentry{\footnotesize{AcuNav (ICE)}}   
            
         % plot the data point and the corresponding gauss curve 742
            \addplot [very thick,green,domain=mu3-C*sigma3:mu3+C*sigma3]
                {gauss(x,mu3,sigma3)};
            \addlegendentry{\footnotesize{L742}}
        % add some lines and labels
           % draw vertical lines
            %TEE
            \draw [blue,very thick,fill=blue]
                (mu1,0) -- coordinate (A left)  (mu1,yA1);
            %ICE
            \draw [red,very thick,fill=red]
                (mu2,0) -- coordinate (A left)  (mu2,yA2);
            %L742
            \draw [fill=green,green,very thick]
                (mu3,0) -- coordinate (A left)  (mu3,yA3);
               
               
            
            % Plot the dots
            % TEE
            \addplot [only marks,blue]
                table [x index=0,y expr=0] {data1.txt};
            % ICE
            \addplot [only marks,red]
                table [x index=0,y expr=0] {data2.txt};
            % 742
            \addplot [only marks,green]
                table [x index=0,y expr=0] {data3.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By changing `C` only changes the plotted domain ...

Comment: That is correct! Changing the "C" it was just as workaround!

Comment: I guess the remaining "problem" with the legend can be solved, but unfortunately you didn't left a hint what you would like the entry to look like. I you want/need a solution for that, feel free to ask a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117).